# How to tell cleveref to locally not sort references

Tags: cross-referencing, cleveref

[The manual for cleveref](http://tug.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/cleveref/cleveref.pdf) states the following:

> When cleveref typesets lists of multiple cross-references or page-references, the
> default behaviour is to automatically sort the list and compress sequences of consecutive cross-references or page numbers into a reference range. You can change
> this behaviour by supplying one of the following package options:
>
> **sort** Sort lists of cross-references, but don’t compress consecutive references.
>
> **compress** Compress sequences of consecutive references into a reference range,
> but don’t sort the list of cross-references.
>
> **nosort** Neither sort lists of cross-references, nor compress consecutive references.
> sort&compress Sort lists of cross-references, and compress sequences of consecutive references into a reference range (this is the default).
>
> Occasionally, you may want to prevent a particular sequence of consecutive
> cross-references from being compressed to a reference range, without disabling
> this feature globally.

However, it does not tell how to locally disable sorting the references. Is it possible to do such a thing?

MWE with output:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{cleveref}

\begin{document}
First equation:
\begin{equation}
\label{equation:first}
    a=2
\end{equation}
Second equation:
\begin{equation}
\label{equation:second}
    b=1
\end{equation}

As seen in \Cref{equation:second,equation:first}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The goal would be to have "As seen in Equations (2) and (1)" without deactivating the sorting at a more global scale.

Comment: you should always show a small but complete example that can be used for a test.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer My bad, that's done!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can locally deactivate the sort feature:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\Crefns}[1]{{\@cref@sortfalse\Cref{#1}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
First equation:
\begin{equation}
\label{equation:first}
    a=2
\end{equation}
Second equation:
\begin{equation}
\label{equation:second}
    b=1
\end{equation}

As seen in \Crefns{equation:second,equation:first}

\end{document}
```

Maybe you want also to deactivate the compress feature:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\Crefns}[1]{{\@cref@sortfalse\@cref@compressfalse\Cref{#1}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
First equation:
\begin{equation}
\label{equation:first}
    a=2
\end{equation}
Second equation:
\begin{equation}
\label{equation:second}
    b=1
\end{equation}

As seen in \Crefns{equation:second,equation:first}

\end{document}
```

[image]

However, note, that this suggestions uses internals of `cleveref`. So it could fail in future, when the internals would change.